# Why does my program get stuck with 'Max retries exceeded' error after a failed HTTPS connection, even with exception handling?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to connect to API and passing all the exceptions but still in certain condition when internet is failing while establishing the connection my code is getting stuck, as in program is not doing anything but the linux service is running with no error.

Recent error message I got:

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.xxx.xx', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/xxx/xx (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xb5ebb868>: Failed to resolve 'api.xxx.xx' ([Errno -3] Try again)"))

Here is the program I'm using:

```py
import os
import time

# Importing custom modules
from pub_data_api import APIPub
from status_led import LED
from log import logger


class PayloadReader:
    def __init__(self):

        self.read_path = '/xxxxxx/'

    def reader(self):
        try:
            lst_dir = sorted(os.listdir(self.read_path))
            for file in lst_dir:
                try:
                    with open(f"{self.read_path}//{file}", 'r') as open_file:
                        payload = open_file.read()
                    if led.internet_status():
                        status_code = api_pub.sendtofwg(payload)
                        if status_code == 201:
                            led.data_led()
                            os.remove(f"{self.read_path}//{file}")
                        else:
                            logger.error(f"Error sending data to Fogwing {status_code}")
                            break
                    else:
                        break
                except Exception as ex:
                    logger.error(ex)
                    pass
        except Exception as ex:
            logger.error(ex)
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    led = LED()
    api_pub = APIPub()
    pub = PayloadReader()
    try:
        while True:
            pub.reader()
            time.sleep(0.3)
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.error(ex)
        pass
```

pub_data_api.py

```
import requests
import json

# Importing custom modules
from log import logger


class APIPub:
    def __init__(self):
        self.api_url = xxxxxx
        self.account_id = xxxxxx
        self.api_key = xxxx
        self.edge_eui = xxxx

    def sendtofwg(self, payload):
        try:
            header = {
                "accountID": self.account_id,
                "apiKey": self.api_key,
                "edgeEUI": self.edge_eui
            }
            payload_resp = requests.post(self.api_url, data=payload, headers=header)
            return payload_resp.status_code
        except Exception as ex:
            logger.error(ex)
            pass
```